# Site doesn't open from remote clients

Tags: error, site

Our SharePoint site stopped being accesible from clients and this happened suddenly this morning. When I try to open the home page from any client IE says that it can't display the web page but when I open the same site locally from the SharePoint server, site runs without problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which kind of authentication ? NTLM or Kerberos or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. According to the IT team, there seems to be a problem with the Windows OS on the server. Although the firewall is disabled on the server completely, all the requests not directed to port 80 are blocked. They are working on it now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your DNS? You could start by pinging the server from the client to make sure there is a network connection available. You could proceed with something like NSLOOKUP or enter your servers IP adress in the clients HOSTS file.

Comment: In fact, there are two web applications running on the same server. One runs on port 80, and the one we can't access runs on port 1500. So I think there isn't a problem with DNS or connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked with your Infrastructure team about any new firewall rules?  With  port 80 being fine and 1500 not accessible, this is something I have seen happen via a new or updated firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex says above, check your DNS, also have you had any updates installed on the server?

Have you tried accessing the page remotely by IP address? If you can access by the IP this will tell you the issue is DNS related.

I have just seen your response that says you can access another site on the same server, that does not mean that you do not have DNS issues, it could be that the site you are trying to access has been removed from DNS. I would still try to access via IP this will then point to network or permissions issues.

Comment: Trying to access by IP doesn't work. None of the sites have dns records. We normally access the sites with the server name, like http://server and http://server:1500.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the other site by IP?

If so it sounds like you have permissions issues or users accounts locked out on the server or in IIS which are used to access the site you can not access.

When you are trying to access the site from other clients are you using the same user? If so can you try another user as well please?

What OS are you hosting on, just to try and give more info please